# Customizing the rich:dataScroller labels wont work

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Im using rich faces 4.1.0 and i do want to customize the rich:dataScroller. I tried doing it in the below way, but still the labels displays as <<<< and <<. Any one knows the solution for this

Thanks!

```
 <rich:dataScroller maxPages="20">
    <f:facet name="first">
        <h:outputText value="First"/>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="last">
        <h:outputText value="Last"/>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="next">
        <h:outputText value="Next"/>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="previous">
        <h:outputText value="Previous"/>
    </f:facet>
</rich:dataScroller>
```

Answer (score 0):

`rich:dataScroller` has `fastControls` as one of its attributes which helps in achieving this.

```
The attribute specifies the visibility of fastControls. Possible values are: "show"    
(controls are always visible ). "hide" (controls are hidden. "auto" (unnecessary controls   
are hidden). Default value is "show".
```

Explanation for this can be found in [rich:dataScroller docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/rich/dataScroller.html). See also

Comment: I tried this adding fastControls="hide", but didn't have much luck :(